# E possível "ocultar" as barras de ferramentas, bookmarks e afins do navegador?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Com o seguinte código, consigo **abrir uma nova janela** ocultando vários componentes do navegador...

```
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:visualControl('newpage.html'); return false;"> 

 SampleText!

</a>

function visualControl(str) {
    window.open(str, 'popupwindowalpha','toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,menubar=no'); 
}
```

**Porem**, eu **já gostaria de abrir a pagina**, ocultando estes componentes, Isso eh possível?

**OU** ainda, que fosse possível, **ligar e desligar** estes componentes **na mesma pagina**...

*detalhe importante, eh para uma **aplicação interna**, para a intranet da empresa, apenas para deixar o **visual mais limpo**, não deseja retirar a liberdade do funcionário.

obrigado!

Comment: Felizmente, não. Inclusive, no Opera até a versão 12, dava pra ocultar os controles, mas o usuário podia ativá-los a qualquer momento, mesmo na nova janela (ou popup) o que é o ideal no meu ver. Se sua aplicação não funcionar bem com voltar, avançar, ou digitação de coisas no URL, é defeito da aplicação. Mas quase tudo tem solução razoável. Se precisa realmente desse controle, é sinal de que pode ser o caso de App nativo, que é a única forma de ter uma UI completamente previsível, e de dar uma experiência do usuário mais elaborada (ou péssima, depende das suas habilidades kkk).

Comment: app nativo? o que seria isso por favor??

Comment: Um executável feito para a máquina, sem os limites do browser. Um programa que rode no windows, fora do browser, ou que seja instalado no aparelho celular, sem a camada "web" comprometendo a interatividade. Faz uns 10 anos que eu vejo gente falando que o browser ia substituir isso, não só falharam, como nos próximos 10 anos tenho tranquilidade em dizer que não vai acontecer. Hoje temos linguagens e frameworks deveras interessantes, em que você reaproveita o código e compila para vários sistemas, como a Qt, por exemplo, que é baseada em C++, mas abstrai grande parte das complexidades.

Answer (score 1):

Não dá pra fazer isso da forma que vc deseja, porém existe duas formas de fazer algo parecido com isso.

1. Utilizando uma API HTML5 [Full Screen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API), para deixar em tela cheia
2. Utilizando fazendo um aplicativo para desktop com [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/), utilizando tecnologia web como html, css e javascript. Utilizando este, por padrão vem oculto toda a barra de navegação